# Error in deploying python-django app with Apache and mod_wsgi in RHEL

Tags: python, django, deployment, mod-wsgi

I am unable to deploy Django-Python application with Apache and mod_wsgi in RHEL.

Below is my configuration:

```
Alias /static /home/appuser/xxxweb/yyydep/app/static
<Directory /home/appuser/xxxweb/yyydep/app>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/appuser/xxxweb/yyydep/app/management>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess management python-path=/home/appuser/xxxweb/yyydep python-home=/home/appuser/xxxweb/yyydep/disneyenv
WSGIProcessGroup management
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/appuser/xxxweb/yyydep/app/management/wsgi.py
```

After restarting the apache server below is the error which has been logged.

Security update check failed: Couldn't connect to server for https://securitycheck.phusionpassenger.com:443/v1/check.json (if this error persists check your connection security or try upgrading Passenger) (next check in 24 hours)
ImportError: No module named site

Can any of them help me to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Shravan,
Which version of RHEL are you using?

Comment: I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

Comment: Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands in shell first and see what happens:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: when executing the above commands iam getting command not found.

Comment: -bash-4.2$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
-bash: firewall-cmd: command not found
-bash-4.2$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
-bash: firewall-cmd: command not found
-bash-4.2$ firewall-cmd --reload
-bash: firewall-cmd: command not found